# ajax request not working in ie11 in file:/// open mode

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm using ajax in my application and i'm using ie11 in my computer. The ajax request was worked in ie10 in the file open(`file:///`) mode, but in ie 11 its throwing an error as `access is denied`.I have googled lot i didn't find a good solution.
Here is the ajax which i used

```
var jsonData;    
$.holdReady(true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: 'JsonData/studentDetails.json',
        success: function (data) {
            jsonData = data;
            $.holdReady(false);
        }
        error: function(obj,data,error){
         debugger;
        }
    });
```

How can use ajax in ie11 and how to open a html file from local drive in ie11?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**EDIT :** I found this [link](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14475) but i confused with this and how to apply this fix and where?

Comment: You'll need a webserver

Comment: Think url's not directly hitting the file system.

Comment: this one wont work in chrome/ff neither I think. you have security restrictions when you work with the file system. try it on a web server and it should work.

Comment: That jQuery bug report has been fixed, though it's possible it's not in any of the production releases yet, or you may be using an earlier version of jQuery that doesn't include the fix. You'd need to edit your jquery.js file and modify the correct line.

Comment: Loading ajax data from `file:///` URLs is always going to break; it violates the browser's security model. I'm surprised you got it working in IE10, to be honest. It can be made to work by lowering the security settings; maybe that's what you did in IE10? But I wouldn't recommend doing that if you can avoid it, and you certainly can't expect other users to do that.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I have tried with updated jquery file version 2.0.3, but it doesn't make any changes.

Comment: I believe older versions of IE10 and also Firefox still allow ajax calls to local files. The most recent browsers don't. This is a problem because not every HTML page is served from a webserver. On the other hand, it would be weird if any HTML page could grab a file from your local file system. But in my opinion it should work if the html file itself is also opened from the same file url.